# Exibir uma string em um campo de texto que está bloqueado para edição

Tags: java, swing

Desenvolvi um chat cliente-servidor e estou incrementando algumas funções para deixa-lo mais apresentável e completo. Uma coisa que ainda não sei como faz é exibir uma string dentro de um campo de texto.

Assim que eu executo o programa, peço para que o usuário digite seu nome em campo de diálogo e armazeno em uma string.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que essa string fosse mostrada em um campo de texto (abaixo a foto do chat e do respectivo campo onde quero que seja mostrado a String nome).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Forneça um codigo que seja um **[mcve]**, assim será possivel qualquer um executar e testar.

Comment: Apenas quero saber como exibir uma string em um Campo de texto. Não há necessidade de postar todo o código pois o restante está funcional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não forneceu um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), mas nos testes que fiz, não houve problema algum utilizar [`settext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText-java.lang.String-) para definir o texto do `JTextField`, mesmo que esteja bloqueado pra edição:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

O fato do campo estar bloqueado para edição ou até mesmo esteja desativado não impede de ser inserido/alterado/apagado texto nele, desde que seja feito programaticamente.